# PHP table bulk action delete

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, html-table

I am using checkboxes in HTML table and what I am trying to do is using a bulk action.
Like if someone checks two or three checkboxes and use the bulk delete action, so all checked items from the table should be deleted.

[image]

Here is my HTML code

```
              <table id="datatable_example" class="responsive table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0; ">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="width:0px; padding-right:0px;" class="no_sort"> <label class="checkbox ">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                  </label>
                </th>
                <th style="width:200px;" class="no_sort"> Institue </th>
                <th style="width:150px;" class="no_sort"> Education </th>
                <th style="width:300px;" class="no_sort"> Description </th>
                <th style="width:150px;" class="ue no_sort"> Started </th>
                <th style="width:150px;" class="ue no_sort"> Completion </th>
                <th class="ms no_sort "> Actions </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php echo $educations ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

EDIT:
This is the Body Section of the Table. As I am working in PHP so I made it something like this.

```
    $educations .= "<tr>
                <td><label class=\"checkbox\">
                    <input type=\"checkbox\">
                  </label></td>
                <td class=\"to_hide_phone\"> $institue_name</td>
                <td class=\"to_hide_phone\"> $education_name</td>
                    <td>$education_desc</td>
                <td>$education_started</td>
                <td>$education_ended</td>
                <td class=\"ms\">
                <div class=\"btn-group1\"> 
                <a href=\"education-edit.php?id=$education_id\" class=\"btn btn-small\" rel=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"left\" data-original-title=\" edit \">
                <i class=\"gicon-edit\"></i></a> 
                <a class=\"btn btn-small\" rel=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" data-original-title=\"View\">
                <i class=\"gicon-eye-open\"></i>
                </a> 
                <a class=\"btn  btn-small\" rel=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"bottom\" data-original-title=\"Remove\"><i class=\"gicon-remove \"></i></a> 
                </div>
                </td>
              </tr>";
```

I want to do that if I select/check two rows and I click the delete action then both rows should be deleted.
I want to know how to perform this action.

Sorry if I am not being clear, I am trying but can't figure out how to implement it.

---

Update:
Here what I have tried so far from your help.

HTML Area:

```
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
        <div class="content top">
          <table id="datatable_example" class="responsive table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0; ">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="width:0px; padding-right:0px;" class="no_sort"> <label class="checkbox ">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes">
                  </label>
                </th>
                <th style="width:200px;" class="no_sort"> Institue </th>
                <th style="width:150px;" class="no_sort"> Education </th>
                <th style="width:300px;" class="no_sort"> Description </th>
                <th style="width:150px;" class="ue no_sort"> Started </th>
                <th style="width:150px;" class="ue no_sort"> Completion </th>
                <th class="ms no_sort "> Actions </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php echo $educations ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="row-fluid control-group">
            <div class="pull-left span6 " action="#">
              <div>


                <div class="controls inline input-large pull-left">                    
                  <select name="bulkaction" data-placeholder="Bulk actions: " class="chzn-select " id="default-select">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="delete">Delete</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="submitbulkaction" class="btn btn-inverse inline">Apply</button></form>
```

Inside tbody area:

```
    $educations .= "<tr>
                <td><label class=\"checkbox\">
                    <input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"chk_boxes1\" name=\"ids[]\" value=\"$education_id\">
                  </label></td>
                <td class=\"to_hide_phone\"> $institue_name</td>
                <td class=\"to_hide_phone\"> $education_name</td>
                    <td>$education_desc</td>
                <td>$education_started</td>
                <td>$education_ended</td>
                <td class=\"ms\">
                <div class=\"btn-group1\"> 
                <a href=\"education-edit.php?id=$education_id\" class=\"btn btn-small\" rel=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"left\" data-original-title=\" edit \">
                <i class=\"gicon-edit\"></i></a> 
                <a class=\"btn btn-small\" rel=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"top\" data-original-title=\"View\">
                <i class=\"gicon-eye-open\"></i>
                </a> 
                <a class=\"btn  btn-small\" rel=\"tooltip\" data-placement=\"bottom\" data-original-title=\"Remove\"><i class=\"gicon-remove \"></i></a> 
                </div>
                </td>
              </tr>";
```

The Part that executes when I press APPLY button:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submitbulkaction']))
{
    $ids = array();
    foreach ((array) $_POST['ids'] as $id) {
    // sanitize input
    $id = (int) $id;
    if ($id) $ids[] = $id;
}
// good idea to say how much row will be deleted to DB
    $limit = count($ids);
    if ($limit) {
    // can see the output
    $ids = join(',', $ids);
    mysql_query("DELETE * FROM cv_education WHERE id IN ($ids) LIMIT $limit");
}
}
```

Well Now I am not getting any error, but also data is not being deleted from database tables too.

My table name is:

cv_education

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your bootsrap css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set checkbox'es like `<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="<?=$data['id']?>">`.

`ids[]` will give you an array.

And then you can process each checkbox like this to collect `ids` that will be deleted;

```
$ids = array();
foreach ((array) $_POST['ids'] as $id) {
    // sanitize input
    $id = (int) $id;
    if ($id) $ids[] = $id;
}
// good idea to say how much row will be deleted to DB
$limit = count($ids);
if ($limit) {
    // can see the output
    $ids = join(',', $ids);
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM cv_education WHERE edu_id IN ($ids) LIMIT $limit");
}
```

Comment: Thankyou 4 reply, sir i am week in PHP.
the ids[] should be empty as it is? or do i need to put value in between"[]" braces?

Comment: No, you won't put anything between braces, just fill up `input value` with `row id` that coming from "db" while writing out them (so you showed in graph)

Comment: I think it's `$education_id` and can write like; `value="<?=$education_id?>"`

Comment: Ok. sir i did it, but i am getting Error in the process of foreach.
its saying invalid argument
"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\pakistanihaider\admin\education.php on line 11"

What to do?

Comment: OK, see update (just convert even it's empty; `foreach ((array) $_POST['ids'] as $id)`)

Comment: Great.. with this update the error is gone.
But still nothing happens when i press APPLY button. I mean it the columns don't get deleted also i don't get any error.

I have updated the code in my first post that what i have done so far with your help..

Comment: Many Many Thanks. just needed to rename the id in query. sorry i should have mentioned the column names in first post.

Many Thanks. You were great Help thou..
Thanks Again :)

Answer (score 1):

first, name your input like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedRows[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
```

then, handle it in posted php file like

```
var_dump($_POST['selectedRows'])
```

`$_POST['selectedRows']` will be an array, which contains values you selected.

If you want to use this array in your sql query, use [implode](http://php.net/implode) and `IN`  like

```
// filter id's first for security.
$ids = array_map('intval',$_POST['selectedRows']);

mysqli_query("DELETE * FROM table_name WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$ids).")");
```

Comment: array_map above should be reversed, with call back first.  **$ids = array_map('intval',$_POST['selectedRows']);**

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see the code that produces `$educations` but the idea is this:

Your checkboxes would look like this:

`<input type="checkbox" name="educations[]" value="<?php $row['id']?>" />`

And when you submit the form you would do:

```
foreach($_POST['educations'] as $value){
    // query
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id = " . $value);
}
```

This is just a guideline. You're open to sql injection.

Comment: so you mean it will not be safe for sql injection?
is there then any safer way?

Comment: Just [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) your posted data.